# Create autoIncrement column using Devexpress xtragrid

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

Using vb.net datagridview I have made autoincrement column. Using the following code:

```
    Private Sub Dgv_RowCountChanged()
          For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgvProm.Rows
          dgvr.Cells(0).Value = dgvr.Index + 1
    Next
    End Sub
```

After I moved to DevExpress xtra grid control I wanted to do the same thing. I have try something like this but it is not good.

```
        Private Sub GridView1_RowCountChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCountChanged
    For Each dgvr As XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridRow 

        Dim s As String = dgvr.VisibleIndex + 1
        MessageBox.Show(s)
    Next

End Sub
```

Any idea how can i do this. This is my first question here.

Devexpress 11.1.4 , Winforms, Grid control

Comment: Why it is not good? It's unclear what are you looking for.

Comment: I want to count numbers of rows my dataGrid and show it into first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , after a lot of research I seem to have found a solution. It goes like this:

```
 Private Sub GridView1_InitNewRow_1(sender As Object, e As InitNewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.InitNewRow

        ' auto increment first column
        GridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "COLUMN", GridView1.RowCount + 1)   ' I want to start from one

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event `InitNewRow` for the `GridView`.

```
private void gv_InitNewRow(object sender, InitNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var myobject = gv.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as MyType;
    var previousmax = /* sth */ <- you can use gv.RowCount or something else
    myobject.NewValue = previousmax + 1;
}
```